# word cloud is not working with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, word-cloud

I had made an exe which shows word cloud .Now when i run it and its shows me the error

python 3.6,windows ,pyinstaller,wordcloud

```
sdf = rdf
comment_words = ' '
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
for val in sdf.Sentence:
        val = str(val)
    tokens = val.split()
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower()
    for words in tokens:
        comment_words = comment_words + words + ' '
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 100, height = 100, 
            background_color ='grey', 
            stopwords = stopwords, 
            min_font_size = 5).generate(comment_words)
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None) 
plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
plt.axis("equal") 
plt.title('Word Cloud', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':4})

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
File "TextTrics V1.0.4.py", line 71, in view_stats
File "visual.py", line 52, in show_visuals
File "wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 605, in generate
File "wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 587, in generate_from_text
File "wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 426, in generate_from_frequencies
File "wordcloud\wordcloud.py", line 473, in generate_from_frequencies
File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 261, in truetype
File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 144, in __init__
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Comment: can you provide source code ?

Comment: i had updated the code

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe late but I had the same problem today and here is how I fixed it :

- I downloaded all the files included in the folder `wordcloud` from the github of the wordcloud project: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/tree/master/wordcloud
- I put all those files in the folder: `dist/name_of_your_py_file/wordcloud/` which is automatically generated (and is empty) after I successfully run `pyinstaller name_of_your_py_file.py`.

Comment: This is still a problem in June 2022. I also did as @Ange Tato recommended.  However I only needed to copy the `stopwords` file and the font file from that folder and everything started working.